# Can't compile the project. Missing so many files

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I just download a ASP.NET mvc 5 + angularjs template version. But i can't build the project. I have updated all VS, Nuget, .Net core, and all to newest version but still no luck. I also try to reinstall all packages but errors are still exists.

Any suggestion ?

[image: ฺBuild error screenshot]

Comment: try to download the zip again and unzip. It might be some of the files are missing

Comment: I have tried but nothing is better

Comment: The messages at the bottom (without a code) urge you to "enable NuGet restore". Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, i do. and i also run reinstall all packages.

Answer (score 0):

navigate to the solution folder in command prompt and run `dotnet restore`

Comment: Still without luck l and I get this message "Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore."

Answer (score 0):

I decide to go for .NET Core version, since it is newest tech. And i can compile it normally, by running "dotnet restore" on the solution folder.

Comment: actually .net core version is the way to go. right choice! always follow the newest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please update TypeScript and then Build. I hope it will resolve.
2. If not then please delete package folder and rebuild the solution.

if you are using VS 2015 then download TS from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593).