# How to config Service and UI view

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Reference to my previous question: [Can't compile the project. Missing so many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660513/cant-compile-the-project-missing-so-many-files)

I am very new to .NET core version. So I have so a few questions need someone to guide me to a quick start.

1. There are 2 templates version for ASP.NET core 2.0; .NET core and .NET full. Does it mean if I choose the .NET full version, I still can use 3rd party DLL such as iTextSharp or EPPlus version, doesn't it? 'Cause I have read that with .NET core, all 3rd party DLL without .NET core support could not be used in the project.
2. From the download template, it contains 2 main projects, one is .NET core service and another is angular UI view. Currently, it set to localhost for all API calls. Because I run the window server in my VM and run the client on my host so I need to set the client to look for the service on my VM via IP address. Which file do I need to config?
3. Related to Q2, how to config the .NET service to run in production mode and install into IIS server?

Thx in advance for all comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to the second question;

There's a config file in `src/assets/appconfig.json`
You can change those values...

- **remoteServiceBaseUrl**: Used to configure base address of the server
  side APIs. Default value: http://localhost:22742
- **appBaseUrl**: Used
  to configure base address of the client application. Default value:
  http://localhost:4200

**appBaseUrl** is configured since we use it to define format of our URL. If we want to use tenancy name as subdomain for a multi-tenant application then we can define appBaseUrl as

---

[Aspnet Zero Angular Getting Started](https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Getting-Started-Angular)

---

PS: Apart from the framework configuration; be aware that connecting something in VM is another discussion. You need to set some settings like Bridged Networking... You can figure it out in the related VM's board.

Comment: Now i can config the server endpoint from angular view. But it seems that now the server service just listening to only localhost connection. I try to change from localhost to server ip address at src/xxx.web.host/appsetting.json or follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725455/connecting-to-visual-studio-debugging-iis-express-server-over-the-lan still no luck. any suggest ?

Comment: it's normal. server needs to listen always itself (localhost). how do you think a server can retrieve requests from another server?

Comment: sorry could you tell where this  appconfig.json lies for mvc dotnetcore ?

Answer (score 1):

- For point 1 you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40108597/6527049) post.
- For Point 2: You can host your service application on Azure or IIS so
  that you can consume your service from other PC.
- For Point 3, Its pretty well explained [here](https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Development-Guide-Angular#deployment).

Additional: If you want to deploy Angular application, you can refer [Deployment of Angular Application](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Angular#deployment-of-angular-application)

You can also refer **src/assets/appconfig.json** for required configurations.

Comment: Thx for a quick reply. But for point 2, my question is how/where to config the service end point. I will look into both refer later on.